# Unit test for private method in angular2 with service injection

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have a private method, In which I am calling a method defined in service to get some data. That service is a class

some snap of code in Angular2

```
private _data: DataService;
private _result: any;

private _getData() {
    this._data.fetchingDetails('userID', (res) => {
        this._result = res;
    });
}
```

How would I test this piece of code in Jasmine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write unit testing for Angular 2 / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to do some hacking to get around the fact that it is a private method, look at Makoto's comment for that.

But generealy you would test it by testing the public method that uses the private one, it has to get called somewhere in your class. For example

```
export class Example 1 {
   constructor() {}
   public foo() {
      this.bar()
   }
   private bar() {
     ... do awesome stuff ...
   }
}
```

here you would test the foo() class to have the expected behavior, including the behaviour in bar().

In your example, if you want to verify that data.fetDetails gets called, then spy on it and test your equvilant to foo.