# Angular 4 Jasmine Spy unit test "Expected undefined to be 'New text'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a simple function modifying a parameter inside my app.component.ts, and I want to test the function using a spy. My changeText function is always undefined for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

**AppComponent.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    text = "My text";

    changeText = function () {
        this.text = "New text";
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.spec.ts**

```
describe("my text with Spies", function () {  
      it("should be altered", function () {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const app = this.fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

      spyOn(app, 'changeText');

      expect(app.text).toBe("My text")    
      expect(app.changeText()).toBe("New text");          //Fails
      expect(app.changeText).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: The spec fails with error "Expected undefined to be 'New text' So the output of changeText is undefined for some reason.

Comment: maybe reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja?rq=1 could be a scoping issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this changes if this is still actually

Change this:

```
expect(app.changeText()).toBe("New text");
expect(app.changeText).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

to:

```
app.changeText();
expect(app.text).toBe("New text");
expect(app.changeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Seems good, but could you elaborate in edit why this will fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, sure. Because your changeText() method changed the this.text, so you should check this text. Also you can write const text = app.changeText() and then expect(text ).toBe("New text"). If you want to check return value.

Comment: I meant add this to you answer. Generally try to describe the code which should help. What does it do, why OP's code doesn't work etc.

Comment: Next time. Thanks for advice.