# What is the best practice to test private methods in Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I've created Angular 5 project and writing unit tests using Karma, Jasmine. I don't like the idea of making all methods public only for accessing from tests.

```
export class AppComponent {
    mainMenu: any[];

    constructor(
        private menuService: MenuService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initTable();
        this.initMenu();
    }

    private initTable(): void {
        // ... initializes array for table
    }

    private initMenu(): void {
        this.menuService.getMainMenu()
            .subscribe(data => this.mainMenu = data);
    }
}
```

`initTable` and `initMenu` methods are just helpers for dividing the code and make more organized and readable, I don't need them to be accessible in `public` mode. But here I'm facing the problem with unit testing, here's how my test case should look like:

```
it ('Should call menuService.getMainMenu', () => {
    spyOn(menuService, 'getMainMenu').and.returnValue(Observable.of([]));

    // this will throw exception
    component.initMenu();

    expect(menuService.getMainMenu).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, they're private, which means you won't be able to test them. You could make them (temporarily) public, test them, get your product owner to see it and add to the code coverage file, then convert them back to private.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write unit testing for Angular 2 / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this via the public `ngOnInit` method. Instead of calling `initMenu` in your test, you can call `ngOnInit` which indirectly calls the private `initMenu`

```
it ('Should call menuService.getMainMenu', () => {
    spyOn(menuService, 'getMainMenu').and.returnValue(Observable.of([]));

    // this will throw exception
    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(menuService.getMainMenu).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Private methods are private for a reason. If you have a private method, which is complicated and you need to test it, it is a code smell, indicating a problem with your code or the method should not be private

Comment: From the pov of `code-coverage` it's not solution, in this situation `code-coverage` willn't cover `initTable` and `initMenu` methods