# Unit test does not pass even though it obviously should?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have a simple function that I am wanting to test, however the obvious outcome is not occurring...

**How my function works (In practise it does work, it just isn't testing properly)**

1. I pass a string into my function
2. If it matches with an element of my array

   3. Returns the string
3. If it does not match an element  of my array

   5. returns string 'default'

When I run the test shown, I receive the error:

> Expected 'default' to equal 'hare-failure

**My Component**

```
const state = [
   {name: 'failure'}
];

isStatus(current): string {
    for (const status of this.state) {
      if (status.name === current) {
        return current;
      }
    }
    return 'default';
  }
```

**My Test**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EventComponent, ConfirmationComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
      providers: []
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
  }));

it('should return current status if it is part of exceptional statuses', () => {
    const returned = component.isState('failure');
    expect(returned).toEqual('failure');
  });
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked as it should, but using const for a classmember in a component is not allowed. Where exactly do you define `exceptionalRaceStatuses`?

Comment: This is abridged code. ExceptionalRaceStatuses are assigned after splitting my JSON into exceptional and unexceptional arrays, but are pretty much like this, except not const of course.

Comment: Okay, I find it hard to pinpoint the exact problem without knowing more details, but it seems to be a problem with the assignment of `exceptionalRaceStatuses`. If it works, but just not in the test, maybe you're doing something different before calling `isStatusExceptional` (not only `ngOninit`)?

Comment: True. I will investigate further. It is a private function in reality, so testing isn't necessary, I just like to have the practise.

Comment: You can test the method while keeping it `private` like this: `component['isStatusExceptional'](string)`. See related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991491/10104739).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use the for-of loop in this case.
You may re-write the component using **some()** method for Arrays, and create a pure function.

So, instead of:

```
isStatusExceptional(currentStatus): string {
for (const status of this.exceptionalRaceStatuses) {
  if (status.name === currentStatus) {
    return currentStatus;
  }
}
return 'default';
```

}

write:

```
isStatusExceptional(current, erc = this.exceptionalRaceStatuses): string {
  return erc.some(item => item.name === current) ? current : 'default';
}
```

Comment: Your code, although it works and is more elegant, still doesn't solve my Testing problem...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your use of `const` in your loop is the issue. You should use `let` here because using `const` prevents reassignment of the value as the loop progresses.

```
isStatusExceptional(currentStatus): string {
    for (let status of this.exceptionalRaceStatuses) {
      if (status.name === currentStatus) {
        return currentStatus;
      }
    }
    return 'default';
  }
```

[Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) seem to agree with this.

Comment: My Lint just complains when it is 'let' instead of 'const' here, but neither causes the code to fail in practise, but still failing in the test? :-/

Comment: Linters can be configured in many ways, but yeah that's going to matter with code execution. I think Stanislav has a better answer.