# Jasmine check if private method has been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular service exposing a public method. Inside its body two different private methods can be called according to a condition. 
**How can I check with jasmine whether one or the other method has been called, according to the input parameter passed to the public method?** I know we should not test private methods, but indeed here I just want to verify whether the public one calls the right private method. I do not want to make the private methods public, as I want only one point of access provided by the service.

**My service methods:**

```
public  addOrUpdateShoppingList(list: ShoppingList) {
  if (!list) {
    return Promise.reject("List object is null!");
  }

  if (!list.id) { 
    return this.createNewList(list);
  }

  return this.updatelist(list);
}

private createNewList(list: ShoppingList) {
  const id = this.db.createId();
  list.id = id;
  return this.db.collection<ShoppingList>(this.SHOPPING_LIST_COLLECTION)
                .doc(id)
                .set(list);
}

private updatelist(list: ShoppingList) {
  return this.db.collection<ShoppingList>(this.SHOPPING_LIST_COLLECTION)
                .doc(list.id)
                .update(list);
```

}

**Jasmine test:**

```
it("addOrUpdateShoppingList should invoke createNewList() if the list doesn't have id.", () => {
const service: DataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
const mockedList: ShoppingList[] = [
  {
    id: null,
    isActive: true,
  }
 ];

service.addOrUpdateShoppingList(newList);

// I tried even with this "workaround", but it fails, even if the private method is accessed
const sp = spyOn<any>(service, "createNewList").and.callThrough();
expect(sp).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test the private methods directly - after all that is the POINT of private methods: they can't be seen outside the class in which they are defined.  For a couple of work-arounds see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja).

However in your case you are in luck.  Both of your private methods make a call to the database service.  Simply spy on that service call and test what was passed - are you trying to `set` or to `update` - this will determine which inner private method was called.