# Angular testing private methods

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I've built a kinda Queue manager which works with RxJs observables and executes them one by one. Now I want to test this, however all the methods that I want to test are private.

Public interface has only two methods that create an observable and add it to the queue manager.

If I try to make something like `spyOn(myService, 'privateMethod')` PhpStorm analysis says that it is not assignable to type (and refers to public methods).

I can't extract this into something where these would become public because it's a complicated logic which should not be interrupted from the outside.

Comment: Dup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja

Comment: frankly @trichetriche the link you claim to be a duplicate answers the question in a sense of testing. However if OP want to add a spy on them it does not show how.

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins I've undeleted my answer so that he can see it, it should be enough.

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins by the way, the duplicate do explain how to access private members of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `spyOn<any>(myService, 'privateMethod')` to bypass that.

But if your methods are private, they shouldn't be tested, they should be implementation details. You should instead test the end result of your public functions.

Comment: it's true, "should not be tested". I assume it's a sin, but I've used spies on private methods (like you describe) to mock up a state (say use return value) or verify that certain action has been taken without need to create any more complicated environment these private methods might interact with.

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins instead of mocking the private methods, you should mock the providers (`HttpClient` most of the times) and leave your private methods as is. I'm talking about best practice here, I'm not forcing you to do it, you do what you want. I'm just telling you what a clean and easy to maintain code looks like.

Comment: well requests to HttpClient is the easy one since we have HttpTestController. Otherwise mocking external dependency used by a private method or spying on a private method to override is a matter of syntax/looks not substance

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins it is a matter of substance. Mocking the methods implies that on the slightest change, you have to remock your spies. Mocking the dependency means that if the slightest change occurs, you just have to edit the dependency, and changes would be repercuted all over the tests. Again, I'm not telling you how to code, I'm merely explaining best practices. There's reasons for them being best practices, no matter your arguments, you can't go against them.

Comment: The problem is that my private methods cannot become public and are interconnected.

Comment: @Sergey then it's either a bad design, or as said before, an implementation detail. But at least now you know how to bypass linting errors !

Comment: "Only testing public methods" doesn't really apply for directives which lacks a public API but only performs some things without a testable end result in the class itself.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz they lack a public API because you chose to, not by design. You can totally test a directive with only its public properties if you have implemented them.

Comment: How do you unit test individual calculations then?