# Access a private variable in spec.ts, Angular6

Tags: angular

I am using a private variable in Angular-6 service.ts.

```
private tagSubject = new Subject<any>();
```

It is been used like

```
  sendNewTagMessage(message: string) {
    this.tagSubject.next({ text: message });
  }

  clearNewTagMessage() {
    this.tagSubject.next();
  }
```

I want to write a unit test for tagSubject.

I cant do `service.tagSubject.subscribe` in the **spec.ts** as it is giving error like `Property 'tagSubject' is private and only accessible within class`. What can I do now. Please help.

Comment: Did you try making it **public**? Or else if you need to make it as private, create a new public variable and assign tagSubject to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write unit testing for Angular 2 / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-2-typescript-for-private-methods-with-ja)

Comment: I think you should be testing the methods sendNewTagMessage and clearNewTagMessage, there is no reason to test Subject since its a well know library.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`component['tagSubject']`

or

`(component as any).tagSubject`

Comment: Thanks, @elzoy. `(component as any)` did the trick for me.

Comment: @elzoy this works for me too, but what exactly is this doing?