# How to write a unit test for typed class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been learning to write unit tests of JavaScript/TypeScript code using Jest library. Here's an example I don't know how to approach to. It's typed with TypeScript - there's only two public methods and a constructor which require service1 argument.

I think I need to test two situations:

- if `this.attr is <= 42` and incrementation happens,
- if `this.attr is > 42` and method `end()` fires.

My problems are:

- I can't access `attr` property, it's private and I don't know how to assign any value to it (maybe while making an instance in test but idk how)
- I don't know what's `this.service1.get()` function is. I don't see any implementation of it in code and I don't know how it works. Should I pass it as an argument to an instance of this class?
- I got confused should I use fakeTimers or mock/spy in this particular example?

```
export class Class4 {
    private attr: number;
    private intervalId;

    constructor(private service1) { }

    public method() {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.service1.get() > 42) {
                this.end()
            } else {
                this.attr++;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    public getAttr() {
        return this.attr;
    }

    private end() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
}
```

I need your help in writing test in Jest only for 2 situations I described.

Edit. 
Here's simple test based on this class. It's not assigning a value of `this.attr` (my argument's value gets assinged to `service1` though) and after running a test I receive an error message

`Expected: 40
Received: undefined`

Code:

```
    it('should stop incrementing Class4.attr if it\'s > 42', () => {
        const class4 = new Class4(40);
        const attrVal = class4.getAttr();
        expect(attrVal).toBe(40);
    });
```

Comment: The example looks incomplete and/or the test makes little sense as it's stated because the incrementation depends on `this.service1.get()`, not `this.attr`. That said, regarding your problems, 1) you can access `this.attr` property since you have the `getAttr` getter, 2) you definitely need an instance of service to call Class4's contructor 2) I don't think you need those for the tests you describe, but it would help to know more details.

Comment: I was also thinking it may be incomplete but I was assured it's enough. If it's possible to test it only partially, it also will be a great answer to my question. 1) But how to assign a value to this.attr in this case? I'll update my question with the simple test that says attr is undefined and I can't find a way to assign a value to it.

Comment: You can't assign attr, attr is the value being incremented every 100ms if service1.get() returns less than 42.

Comment: I've just realized that you received undefined most likely because you never called `method`and therefore `attr` was never incremented.

Comment: That actually could be true, but the main thing is none value was assigned to `attr` before. It's only declared and typed `private attr: number;` so calling `method` returns `undefined`.

Comment: For me that just means the class is flawed and attr has to be initialized.Otherwise attr just can't be incremented and the class has no purpose at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure this can help but below is an example of how you could use Jest to test something like this.

It's your code translated from typescript to es6 with a light fake Jest implementation attached.
It's in a separate script to leave the example itself alone.

The fake Jest only implements the required Jest matchers in this test: [expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectvalue), [toBeGreaterThan](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobegreaterthannumber), [not](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#not), [toHaveBeenCalledTimes](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber).

And the following Jest utilities: [useFakeTimers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimers), [advanceTimersByTime](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun), [clearAllTimers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearalltimers), [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock)

```js
// self calling function is required to simulate Class4 module and for fake Jest mock to work
(function() {
// translated from typescript to es6
class Class4 {
    attr = 0;

    intervalId = null;

    constructor(service1) {
        this.service1 = service1;
    }

    method() {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.service1.get() > 42) {
                this.end();
            } else {
                this.attr++;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    getAttr() {
        return this.attr;
    }

    end() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
}
// this is required to simulate Class4 module and for fake Jest mock to work
window.Class4 = Class4;
})();

// even if we do not know exactly what Service is,
// we know that it has a get method which returns a varying number.
// so this implementation of Service will do
// (it's ok since we're testing Class4, not Service)
class ServiceImpl {
    v = 0;
    set(v) { this.v = v; }
    get() { return this.v; }
}

// after this call, jest will control the flow of
// time in the following tests
// (reimplements the global methods setInterval, setTimeout...etc)
jest.useFakeTimers();

// actually it should be jest.mock('<path to your module>')
// but remember we're using a fake Jest working in SO's snippet)
// now Class4 is a mock
jest.mock(Class4);

// we need a Service instance for a Class4 object to be instanciated
const service = new ServiceImpl();

const class4 = new Class4(service);

it('Class4 constructor has been called 1 time', () => {
    expect(Class4).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('should be incrementing Class4.attr if service.get() < 42', () => {
    // service.get() will return 40
    service.set(40);

    // storing initial attr val
    let lastAttrVal = class4.getAttr();

    // now class4 is running and should be incrementing
    class4.method();

    // jest controls the time, advances time by 1 second
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);

    expect(class4.getAttr()).toBeGreaterThan(lastAttrVal);
});

it('should have been called Class4.end 0 time', () => {
    expect(Class4.mock.instances[0].end).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
});

it('should stop incrementing Class4.attr if service.get() > 42', () => {
    // service.get() will now return 45, this should end class4
    // incrementation in the next interval
    service.set(45);

    // storing current attr val
    let lastAttrVal = class4.getAttr();

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);

    expect(class4.getAttr()).not.toBeGreaterThan(lastAttrVal);

});

it('end should have been called end 1 time', () => {
    expect(Class4.mock.instances[0].end).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

jest.clearAllTimers();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.jest = {};
jest.useFakeTimers = () => {
    jest.oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    jest.oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
    jest.oldClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
    jest.oldClearInterval = window.clearInterval;
    jest.time = 0;
    jest.runningIntervals = [];
    window.setInterval = (callback, delay) => {
        let interIndex = jest.runningIntervals.findIndex(i => i.cancelled);
        let inter = interIndex !== -1 && jest.runningIntervals[interIndex];
        if (!inter) {
            inter = {};
            interIndex = jest.runningIntervals.length;
            jest.runningIntervals.push(inter);
        }
        Object.assign(
            inter,
            {
                start: jest.time,
                last: jest.time,
                callback,
                delay,
                cancelled: false
            }
        );
        callback();
        return interIndex;
    };
    window.clearInterval = idx => {
        jest.runningIntervals[idx].cancelled = true;
    };
    jest.advanceTimersByTime = advance => {
        for (const end = jest.time + advance;jest.time < end; jest.time++) {
            jest.runningIntervals.forEach(inter => {
                if (!inter.cancelled && jest.time - inter.last >= inter.delay) {
                    inter.last = jest.time;
                    inter.callback();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    jest.clearAllTimers = () => {
        jest.runningIntervals.length = 0;
        window.setTimeout = jest.oldSetTimeout;
        window.setInterval = jest.oldSetInterval;
        window.clearTimeout = jest.oldClearTimeout;
        window.clearInterval = jest.oldClearInterval;
    };
};

jest.resolve = (v) => {
  console.log(v ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL');
}
window.it = (description, test) => {
    console.log(description);
    test();
};
window.expect = (received) => {
  return {
    toBeGreaterThan: (expected) => jest.resolve(received > expected),
    not: {
      toBeGreaterThan: (expected) => jest.resolve(received <= expected),
    },
    toHaveBeenCalledTimes: (expected) => jest.resolve((received ? received.mock.calls.length : 0) === expected),
  }
}
jest.mock = (cls) => {
    if (cls.mock) return;
    const mock = {
        instances: [],
        calls: []
    }
    const proto0 = cls.prototype;

    function ClassMock(...args) {
        mock.calls.push(args);
        
        this.instance = new proto0.constructor(...args);
        this.instanceMock = {};
        mock.instances.push(this.instanceMock);
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto0).forEach((member) => {
          if (member === 'constructor' || typeof proto0[member] !== 'function') return;
          this.instanceMock[member] = this.instanceMock[member] || { mock: { calls: [] } };
          this.instance[member] = (function(...args) {
              this.instanceMock[member].mock.calls.push(args);
              return proto0[member].apply(this.instance, [args]);
          }).bind(this);
      });
    }

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto0).forEach((member) => {
        if (member === 'constructor' || typeof proto0[member] !== 'function') return;
        ClassMock.prototype[member] = function(...args) {
            return this.instance[member](...args);
        }
    });
    
    
    ClassMock.mock = mock;
    window[proto0.constructor.name] = ClassMock;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's well explained! All I can think of - is it possiible to test it without migrating from TypeScript? Is it possible somehow to spy on `method()` and check if it eventually calls `end()` method? I tried to make a mock out of it, but since it's private method I'm not allowed, but maybe there is a correct way?

Comment: Aaah here we're entering the delicate debate of "should we test private methods?".If 1) we shouldn't: just remove the test on the private method being called. if 2) your de develeopper of the private method, you can define it protected instead and create the test in the same package. if 3) you don't want anyone to tell you what to do: preprocess the typescript sources to replace private modifiers by public ones before testing

Comment: You may find this discussion helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-typescript-for-private-methods-with-jasm

Comment: As a side note: compiled typescript may not be able to actually prevent private member access (as at the end of the day typescript is transpilled to es5 and that would be changing the runtime behavior). So wrting the test in es6 and importing the compiled typescript may do the trick.

Comment: I understand. You are very helpful. But still - without assigning `0` (or any other actual number) to `attr` (so without modifying given class) it won't work. Because `method` won't find an assigned number to increment and `getAttr` will be returning undefined (`attr` was only declared but with no value).

Comment: So the test is telling you that the class fails to act as specified and therefore has to be fixed. Isn't it its purpose?