# How to use jest to mock out a private variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for a function like this:

```
export class newClass {
    private service: ServiceToMock;

    constructor () {
    this.service = new ServiceToMock()
    }

    callToTest () {
        this.service.externalCall().then(()=> {
        //Code to test
        })
    }
}
```

In order to test this piece of code I need to mock out service because it calls a function outside of the class but the problem is it's private.

How exactly do I mock out a private variable with jest?  The class creates its own instance of it so is it even possible to mock out?

Comment: why can't you use `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') { this.service = new MockedService(); } else { this.service = new ServiceToMock(); } `?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that.  Doesn't seem ideal to change production code just to test it though.

Comment: Can you edit your code? Your code is not correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write unit testing for Angular / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-typescript-for-private-methods-with-jasm)

Comment: But the title is Jest, not Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

## In your implementation you either import the service

**`implementation.js`**

```js
import ServiceToMock from './serviceToMock.js';
```

**`implementation.spec.js`**

```js
// import the already mocked service
import ServiceToMock from './serviceToMock.js';
import newClass from './implementation';

// auto-mock the service
jest.mock('./serviceToMock.js');

describe('newClass', () => {
  describe('somMethod', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      // it is recommended to make sure
      // the previous calls are cleared
      // before writing assertions
      ServiceToMock.prototype.externalCall.mockClear()

      // jest's auto-mocking will create jest.fn()
      // for each of the service's methods
      // and you will be able to use methods like .mockResolvedValue
      // to modify the mock behavior
      ServiceToMock.prototype.externalCall.mockResolvedValue(data);

      // call your method
      (new newClass).someMethod();
    });

    it('should call ServiceToMock.externalCall', () => {
      // and you can write assertions for the mocked methods
      expect(ServiceToMock.prototype.externalCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });
  });
});
```

[working example without Types](https://repl.it/repls/WildRecklessThings)

## Or have the implementation within the file

In that case you'll have to test the both classes as that is your Unit

Comment: my externalCall method returns void so mockClear() and mockResolvedValue doesn't work.

Comment: @MatTaNg if it returns void you should not be able to chain `.then` and you need mock clear, because it stores the calls internally

Comment: It returns a promise actually.  I was looking at the wrong function.  Still, it doesn't know what those mock functions are

Comment: @MatTaNg I've updated my answer with a working example

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2227 - shows a cleaner way