# How do I test a private method in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 11 project and I don't know how to Test a private method.

here is an Code Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addSubscription(this.myServiceFacade.myService.reloadEvent.subscribe(
        this.foo.bind(this)
    ));
}

private foo() {
    this.myString = 'test';
    this.bar(MyStatus.Enum);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note also: [How to write unit testing for Angular / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35987055/69809)

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER** This trick should only be used for tests, never for production!

There's a typescript trick you can use to access private members - use the indexing operator with the member in a string, thus:

```js
someObjectWithPrivateMembers['privateMemberName']();
```

And the nice thing is, you get to keep type safety, because typescript looks up the type of the private member.

Be careful not to have a typo in the string (to a non existent member), because typescript won't complain, and the result will be undefined with a type of `any`.

Comment: Also possible to use `any` to bypass the type system: `(someObjectWithPrivateMembers as any).privateMemberName();`

Comment: got error saying "this" is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You  test private methods by calling public methods. Create a test bed for your component, create a mock of `myServiceFacade` such that it dispatches a reload event and verify that after that `myString` is equal to `'test'`