# How to write angular Unit test private?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

> I have a private method

```
private checkProjectType(el: Project) {
 switch (el.type) {
   case 'Blue':
     return this.handleBlueCheck(el);
   case 'Red':
     return this.handleRedCheck(el);
  }
}
```

> Project is define

```
export interface Project {
      id?: string;
      cloneId?: string;
      name?: string;
      description?: string;
      type?: string;
      tips?: string;
  }
```

I don't have experience with Unit Test private which is using jasmine and Karma coverage . Please help me!

Comment: From my perspective, you should not test the private methods directly. I suppose this private method is used somewhere in public space so if you want you can test the private method by calling the public.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write unit testing for Angular / TypeScript for private methods with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987055/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-angular-typescript-for-private-methods-with-jasm)

Comment: You need to test the public methods that call the private one and assert the changes it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should test private method through public.
You can read [here](https://medium.com/@duydnguyen07/unit-testing-private-methods-in-angular-79ab5ff9cf27) about another approaches.
You can try it:

```
 it('should trigger of project type is blue', () => {
projectTypeSpy = spyOn(component, 'handleBlueCheck');

component.project = 'Blue';      // if you aware of project type

//call function that calls your private checkProjectType

  expect(projectTypeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.project);
});
```