# Expect statement on Non-Exposed method + mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Trying to do expect statement on Non-exposed method in node.js..

**myfile.js**

```
function main() {
    try{
    } catch(err) {
        a();
    }
}       
           
function a() {
    return true/false
}
module.exports = {
    main:main
}
```

`a()` is not exported its internal to myfile.js. Now my requirement is in  test file how can i do `expect(a()).to.be.true`. Is it other way to mock this function and do expect statement?. Please share your ideas;

Comment: Unless you can force the error in `main()` to take that path, `a` needs to be exported somehow. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116345/1318694) in the dupe for a method to export functions but a `B` module, but not `A`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unit test non-exported functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116070/how-can-i-unit-test-non-exported-functions)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for sharing.Already have gone through the post , but it doesn't solve my problem, they are exporting it in someway.

Comment: Well, it provides the methods you can use to test it